# Why is .call(this) used instead of parenthesis

Tags: javascript

Is there a particular reason why i often encounter:

```
(function() {
  console.log("Hello");
}).call(this);
```

instead of:

```
(function() {
  console.log("Hello");
})();
```

It should have the same effect when passing `this` to call or not?

There seems to be some performance difference: http://jsperf.com/call-vs-parenthesis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably the code within that function uses `this` (where you just have `console.log`). In the version with `call`, `this` *within* the function is the same as `this` outside it. Without `call`, `this` inside the function is either the global object (loose mode) or `undefined` (strict mode).

If you're not using `this` within the function, there's no reason to be doing the `call` version, and I would lean toward not doing so because it's additional unnecessary complexity (and apparently a **very very small** performance cost).

Comment: So they behave the same way in loose mode but not in strict mode?

Comment: @NickRussler: Only if that code is at global scope (or was otherwise called with `this` being the global object). I assumed it wasn't, that it was in code where `this` *wasn't* the global object (DOM event handlers, etc.).

Comment: @Nick - no, assume that the code OUTSIDE of your IIFE has `this` set to something other than the global object

Comment: Ahh sure, now i got it. Thank you both. AFAIK CoffeeScript compiles files into an anoynmous function that is executed with call, which got me wondering..

Comment: Source for the performance cost? Just want to see if there truly is a performance cost, or if this is just conjecture.

Comment: @codefactor: See the jsperf link in the question.

Comment: I wonder if that jsperf is accurate (not many actual tests ran so far) - I was under the impression that adding a `.call` would not negatively impact performance, and vaguely remembering somewhere that a normal function call is interpreted the same way as `.call` under the covers.

Comment: @codefactor: There's overhead that can't be done away with, so the two can never be *exactly* the same. The engine is required to resolve the `call` property, if nothing else, which is a non-zero-time operation. (Think it can shortcut it? Nope. Consider: http://jsbin.com/eyohUNEY/1/edit) But again, we're talking **very very small**, any additional overhead is almost certain to be washed out by what the function you're calling actually does.

Answer (score 3):

The addition of `.call(this)` is important, it changes the context of the function enclosure, meaning that the `this` keyword will refer to the same `this` as the outer function enclosure.

In your particular code it doesn't make any difference because inside your function you do not refer to `this` at all.

```
this.a = 123;
(function() {
   console.log(this.a); // always 123 regardless of scope
}).call(this);
```

That is significant assuming that `this` refers to something other than the window object. If `this` is already pointing to the window, then adding `.call(this)` makes no difference, since without it, by default the `this` will go to the window.